# unindent does not match any outer indentation level... whats wrong?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hi I have been trying to write a dice rolling program and I just got this error can you tell me whats wrong with my code and offer me a solution to fix it? Thanks.

```
import random
while True:
    dice_type = int(input("would you like to roll a 4,6 or 12 sided dice"))
    if dice_type in[4,6 or 12]:
                    break
                print("Sorry that is not the correct input")

                score = random.randint(1, dice_type)

                print ("The dice you threw was a %d-sided dice" %dice_type)
                print ("You rolled a %d" %score)
```

update:

Ok I have tweaked the program so that it looks like this...

```
import random
while True:
    dice_type = int(input("would you like to roll a 4,6 or 12 sided dice:"))

    score = random.randint(1, dice_type)
    print ("The dice you threw was a %d-sided dice" %dice_type)
    print ("You rolled a %d" %score)
```

It now works. thanks for the quick responses everyone. if you have found a way to make the program reject incorrect values being entered please comment a solution.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I'm getting an IndentationError. How do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45621722/im-getting-an-indentationerror-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your indentation is wrong. Try this.

```
import random
while True:
    dice_type = int(input("would you like to roll a 4,6 or 12 sided dice"))
    if dice_type in [4, 6, 12]: # you also dont need that or
        break
    print("Sorry that is not the correct input")

score = random.randint(1, dice_type)

print ("The dice you threw was a %d-sided dice" %dice_type)
print ("You rolled a %d" %score)
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I am no longer getting the indentation error however when i input the type of dice i would like to use nothing happens.

Comment: Perhaps the `score = ...` line and the ones after it should be de-dented one more level so that they're not considered part of the `while` loop...